# Who approves feature requests?

Tags: support, feature-request-process

Who approves the feature requests made on meta? Is it approved by the SE mods and employees, or is it approved by discussion?

Comment: related: [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](http://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There really isn't such a thing as approving one.

It can get implemented.

The SE team does this.

One of the community managers or the implementing developer will then slap a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) onto it.

Essentially, all feature requests are on the radar of SE employees. Which of those get implemented depends on a number of things, most of which are not public. We only hear from them again when the FR is either declined or implemented, or sometimes [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) or [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review).